# ¿Como agregar el evento onclick a un botón que se crea dinámicamente dentro de una tabla?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la columna de Acciones están los botones en la cual al hacer clic debe aparecer un menú emergente, para ello tengo hecho lo siguiente:

ver_producto.html

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-menu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item">Agregar Fotos</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Detalles</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Modificar</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Eliminar</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn outlined primary">Registrar Producto</button>
        </div>
        <table class="table-productos" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Fotos</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</main>
```

ver_producto.js:

```
const button_options = document.getElementById("btn-options");
const context_menu = document.querySelector(".container-menu");

function showOptions() {
    alert("click");
}

function getProductos() {
    const table_productos = document.querySelector(".table-productos > tbody");
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("get", "http://localhost/app/producto/obtener_productos.php");
    request.onload = () => {
        try {
            const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

            json.forEach((data) => {
                const tr = document.createElement("tr");
            
                const th_codigo = document.createElement("th");
                const td_producto = document.createElement("td");
                const td_descripcion = document.createElement("td");
                const td_total_fotos = document.createElement("td");
                const td_acciones = document.createElement("td");
                const btn_options = document.createElement("button");
                const img_options = document.createElement("img");

                th_codigo.id = "codigo-producto";
                td_total_fotos.id = "total-fotos";
                td_acciones.id = "img-options";
                btn_options.id = "btn-options"
                img_options.src = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5718/5718983.png"
                img_options.width = 15;
                img_options.height = 15;

                th_codigo.textContent = data.codigo_producto;
                td_producto.textContent = data.nombre;
                td_descripcion.textContent = data.descripcion;
                td_total_fotos.textContent = "0";
                btn_options.onclick = showOptions();
                btn_options.appendChild(img_options);
                td_acciones.appendChild(btn_options);
                tr.appendChild(th_codigo);
                tr.appendChild(td_producto);
                tr.appendChild(td_descripcion);
                tr.appendChild(td_total_fotos);
                tr.appendChild(td_acciones);

                table_productos.appendChild(tr);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn("Error: " + error);
        }
    };

    request.send();
}
```

En la clase javascript cuando se crean las filas de la tabla agregue el siguiente código:

> btn_options.onclick = showOptions();

Supongo que esto debería hacer que cada vez que se haga clic en el botón aparezca el mensaje que se encuentra dentro de la función `showOptions()` pero cuando recargo la página el mensaje aparece la cantidad de registros que hay en la tabla, es decir, si hay 20 registros, el mensaje aparece 20 veces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que `btn_options.onclick = showOptions();`, en teoría, debería hacer es asignar a `btn_options.conclick` lo que devuelve la función `showOptions`, lo cual no es lo que estás intentando hacer.

Solución:

```
btn_options.onclick = showOptions;
```

Aquí lo que estás haciendo es asignar la función en sí, ya que si añades los paréntesis estarías ejecutando la función y asignando el valor que devuelve, no la función.

Espero que esto resuelva tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza on para añadir eventos a elementos creados despues de la carga del DOM utilizando JQuery

```
$(".table-productos > thead").append("<tr><th>ID</th><th>Producto</th<th>Descripción</th><th>Fotos</th><th>Acciones</th></tr>");  

$( "tr" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  console.log( "hey!" );
});
```

Comment: Ojo que esto es para jQuery. La pregunta hace referencia a JS.